# Elegant solution for determining which range a numeric value falls into

Tags: javascript, numbers

If I supply a number to a function, how would I go about validating it against a range of numbers like this?

```
1-10  = A
11-20 = B
21-30 = C
...
```

I know I can do `if` statements to evaluate this, but I'm looking for something more elegant because the problem gets a lot more complex and I don't want a nasty web of ifs.

```
var letter = "";

function getLetter(num) {
  if (num >= 1 && num <= 10) {
    letter = "A";
  } else if (num >= 11 && num <= 20) {
    letter = "B";
  }
  // this eventually gets gross
}
```

Expected outcome of `getLetter(14)` would be `"B"`, and `getLetter(49)` would be `"E"`, etc. Case/switch is also off the table for similar reasons.

Any other ideas welcome.

Comment: to be fair, using `if/else if` you don't need to check both lower and upper bounds

Comment: Are the ranges of equal "width"? Or can they be variable width (e.g. `1 - 5, 6 - 10, 11 - 20`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just a point about your code

```
function getLetter(num) {
  if (num >= 1 && num <= 10) {
    letter = "A";
  } else if (num >= 11 && num <= 20) {
    letter = "B";
  }
  // this eventually gets gross
}
```

this can be simplified to

```
function getLetter(num) {
  if (num >= 1) {
    if(num <= 10) {
      letter = "A";
    } else if (num <= 20) {
      letter = "B";
    }
    // this eventually gets gross too
  }
}
```

But:

If it's as simple as every letter represents a range of 10 values:

```js
function getLetter(num) {
  return String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor((num - 1) / 10));
}
console.log(getLetter(1));
console.log(getLetter(14));
console.log(getLetter(49));
```

or as suggested

```js
function getLetter(num) {
  const ret = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
  return ret[Math.floor((num - 1) / 10)] || "+"; // greater than 260
}
console.log(getLetter(1));
console.log(getLetter(14));
console.log(getLetter(49));
console.log(getLetter(261));
```

```js
function getLetter(number) {
  let ranges = {
    a: 10,
    b: 20,
    c: 30,
    underflow: 0,
    overflow: Infinity
  }

  return Object.entries(ranges)
  .sort(([ka, va], [kb, vb]) => va - vb) // because object key sort order isn't guaranteed
                                         // though it will be in the order as declared, but
                                         // sorting makes sense
  .find(([key, value]) => number <= value)[0];
}

console.log(getLetter(5))
console.log(getLetter(17))
console.log(getLetter(20))
console.log(getLetter(30))
console.log(getLetter(31))
console.log(getLetter(0))
```

If the ranges are contiguous, you only need one of the boundaries

Comment: Or if you want to be a bit more free about your letters: Store them in an array and get indices from the array.

Comment: Dang it. I simplified the problem when they aren't all 10 values. You're technically correct and I'll give you the answer for it. This was my boneheaded mistake.

Comment: @PythonIT Could you provide additional context (or code) for your comment?

Comment: @daveycroqet - I added an example

Comment: @daveycroqet Light's answer seems to be just fine for that... It even got modifiable intervals

Comment: I'd recommend to avoid using an unordered object for iterating the ranges. Better make that an array of tuples.

Comment: @Bergi - agreed, I borrowed from Light's answer, made it better, and made it more robust

Answer (score 2):

Works alright if you want to put your ranges into an object, and then loop through that

```js
function getLetter (number) {
  let ranges = {
    a: [1, 10],
    b: [11, 20],
    c: [21, 30],
    d: [31, 36],
    e: [37, 40]
  }

  return Object.keys(ranges).find((key) => {
    let currRange = ranges[key];

    if (number >= currRange[0] && number <= currRange[1]) {
      return key;
    }
  });
}

console.log(getLetter(5))
console.log(getLetter(17))
console.log(getLetter(20))
console.log(getLetter(30))
console.log(getLetter(35))
console.log(getLetter(39))
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This might end up being closer to what I needed, but I think Bravo updated his answer with a workable solution as well.

Comment: The `find` callback should return a boolean, not a string-or-undefined.